# Unable to install GridDB on Fedora

Tags: installation, fedora, griddb

I am trying to install GridDB on my Fedora 33. I am trying to install it using the guide mentioned https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-source-code/ downloaded the latest version using

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/griddb/griddb.git
```

but it's not responding at all.

Is there anything else need to configure to setup GridDB on Fedora 33?

Comment: I was able to `git clone ...`.  "but it's not responding at all"  Is there an error message?

Comment: It's the same case with me as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear.   I was able to clone the git repo without a problem.  Are you able to clone the repo now?

Comment: Yes, thanks its now working for me.